# C# extension with nearly identical methods

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Still a little fresh to C#, I have a "utility" class that I'm wanting to use across multiple internal projects. In one project there's a massive (hundreds of properties, not my doing...) internal object (`SpecialObj`). The other projects have no access to this object and adding it to them is a non-starter, so the base method is unaware of `SpecialObj`.

So here's the rub: MyMethod in both MyClass (doesn't take this special object) and MyClassExtension (does take the special object) have nearly identical code, except for one part in the middle that uses this special object.

```
public class MyClass{
    public string MyMethod (string param1, Dictionary<string, string> param2){
        //some code in here part 1
        //some code in here part 2
    }
}

public class MyClassExtension : MyClass{
    public string MyMethod (string param1, Dictionary<string, string> param2, SpecialOjb param3)
    {
        //some code in here part 1
        //something with param3, my special object
        //some code in here part 2
    }
}
```

Maintaining 90% identical code in two methods seems... very wrong. Are there any examples or standards for this situation?

Comment: Couldn't you get `some code in here part 1` and `some code in here part 2` out in two other methods?

Comment: Can `MyClass::MyMethod` call through to `MyClassExtension::MyMethod` ?

Comment: @DanDumitru that's a really, really good thought... maybe, I'll try that.

Comment: could `SpecialObj` be reduced to an interface that could be taken as an optional parameter to `MyClass.MyMethod`? i.e. `param2, ISpecialObj param3 = null)` and `/* some code in here part 1 */ param3?.DoYourThing(); /* some code in here part 2 */`

Comment: @Igor no, only the other way around

Comment: @MarcGravell Normally that would be appropriate, but given the sheer size and the ingrained nature of this object it's impractical for me to do so.

Comment: @RandyHall I'd just split it into multiple `protected` or even `internal` methods like @DanDumitru suggests.

Comment: @Igor et al - This question is specific enough to have produced the correct answer. If you're going to put it on hold at least leave a comment or some indication of why you feel there isn't enough clarification beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the code into protected parts and call them

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyMethod (string param1, Dictionary<string, string> param2) 
    {
        ProtectedMyMethodPart1( ... );
        ProtectedMyMethodPart2( ... );
    }

    protected void ProtectedMyMethodPart1( ... )
    {
    }

    protected void ProtectedMyMethodPart2( ... )
    {
    }
}
```

and reuse them in the inherited class

```
public class MyClassExtension : MyClass
{
    public string MyMethod (string param1, Dictionary<string, string> param2, SpecialOjb param3)
    {
        ProtectedMyMethodPart1( ... );
        // Do something with param3
        ProtectedMyMethodPart2( ... );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably I will do something like this.

```
 public class MyClass{
    public virtual string MyMethod (string param1, Dictionary<string, string> param2){
      int i= MyCommonCode.MyCommonMethod();
      //I do whatever I like with i here
    }
}

public class MyClassExtension : MyClass{
    public string MyMethod (string param1, Dictionary<string, string> param2, SpecialOjb param3)
    {
      int i= MyCommonCode.MyCommonMethod();
      //I do whatever I like with i here
    }
}

public class MyCommonCode
{
  public static int MyCommonMethod()
  {
    return 1;
  }
}
```